# What is Network-in and Network-out Metrics normal state for EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

I was looking into the CPU utilization of my EC2 instance and found that it was normal. I also went ahead to find the Network-in and Network-out data metrics and also found that below.

My query is what may be or is the normal state/metrics for the EC2 instance. **Is there any boundary for the Network-in matrice that this many bytes/sec of network-in exceeds then it will create a problem for the EC2 server?**

**I just want to know if there is any nominal metrics point that can be used to specify that my EC2 instance Network-in intake is all good.**

Comment: There is no "normal" -- it totally depends on what the software on your EC2 instance is doing. If it is sending lots of network traffic (eg copying large files), then it will show lots of network traffic. If it is simply sitting there waiting for somebody to login, then it will show very little network traffic. The only problem might be if you are trying to send/receive too much data and it will hit the bandwidth limit of the instance. This will appear in the metrics as a very high but flat level of metrics where it seems to hit an upper-limit. This can be common on small T2-family instances.